# Cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Trying to write an object to an array and then save to output.data, then read the objects again.

Writing:

```
private void saveBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    File outFile;
    FileOutputStream fStream;
    ObjectOutputStream oStream;

    try {
        outFile = new File("output.data");
        fStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);

        oStream.writeObject(arr);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Written Successfully");

        oStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Reading:

```
private void readBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    File inFile;
    FileInputStream fStream;
    ObjectInputStream oStream;

    try {
        inFile = new File("output.data");
        fStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        oStream = new ObjectInputStream(fStream);

        //create an array of assessments
        ArrayList <Assessment> xList;
        xList = (ArrayList<Assessment>)oStream.readObject();



        for (Assessment x:xList) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: " + x.getName() + "Type: " + x.getType() + "Weighting: " + x.getWeighting());
        }

        oStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }


}
```

The code comppiles just fine, and the file itself saves alright too. But when I try to read the file nothing happens, and NetBeans says

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lnetbeansswingexample.Assessment; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList"

the line of code giving trouble seems to be

```
xList = (ArrayList<Assessment>)oStream.readObject();
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks. Sorry if the answers obvious, pretty new to programming.

Comment: Because you are serializing an **array**, not the `ArrayList` **object**

Comment: What is the type of `arr` at `saveBtnActionPerformed` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the exception you got, it looks like `oStream.readObject()` returns an array of `Assessment`, not a `List`. You can convert it to a `List`:

```
    List <Assessment> xList;
    xList = Arrays.asList((Assessment[])oStream.readObject());
```

or if you must use a `java.util.ArrayList` :

```
    ArrayList<Assessment> xList;
    xList = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList((Assessment[])oStream.readObject()));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I see where I went wrong now... using an array and not a list like I should have. That code worked perfectly.